# Azure Functions Premium Plan still has cold start after inactivity or deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created a simple Hello World function with an HTTP Trigger using the Azure CLI and deployed this to Azure, North Europe. The code can be seen on [GitHub](https://github.com/jcavell/azure-function-premium). I specified EP2 SKU (premium plan) with 3 minimum instances and 3 pre-warmed instances. I also created a staging slot which I can deploy to and swap this with production.

```
# Create a Premium plan with EP2
az functionapp plan create \
  --name $plan \
  --resource-group $resourceGroup \
  --location $location \
  --min-instances 3 \
  --max-burst 5 \
  --sku EP2 

# Create the Function App
az functionapp create \
  --name $functionAppName \
  --storage-account $storageName \
  --plan $plan \
  --resource-group $resourceGroup

# Create a staging slot
az functionapp deployment slot create \
  --name $functionAppName \
  --resource-group $resourceGroup \
  --slot staging

# Configure for 3 pre-warmed instances
az resource update -g $resourceGroup -n $functionAppName/config/web \
  --set properties.preWarmedInstanceCount=3 \
  --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites
```

The full CLI code to create the resources can be seen on [GitHub](https://github.com/jcavell/azure-function-premium/blob/master/azure/create.sh)

I am still getting cold starts and unacceptably variable response times (reported in the Azure Portal's Monitor section for the HTTP Trigger):

- Average function response time when warm: 3-4ms
- After being idle: up to a second
- Upon staging to production swap, even with staging warmed: 250-500ms
- Randomly, long response times of up to a second

Is there something wrong with my configuration? It cannot be expected behaviour for Azure Functions on the premium plan.

Comment: What the service plan you are using now?

Comment: @Jonny Cavell Do you still have the cold start issue with the premium plan?

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I test it in my side and found the same result as yours. Even though I set the pre-warmed instances, when the function being idle, it will take some more time to response.

But in my test, if I increase the pre-warmed instances, the response time will reduce. So could you please try to increase the pre-warmed instances and request your function again when after it is idle ? You can config the number of pre-warmed instances by following the steps below:

**Go to your function app and click "Platform features" --> "All settings" --> "Scale out(App Service Plan)"**

If it doesn't reduce the response time or the response time still can't match your requirement after increase the pre-warmed instances. I suggest you to raise a support ticket on Azure portal by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). The support team can see the backend code of your function and try to help you.